# How to create a cross join of a list and a dictionary?

Tags: python

I would like to create a cross join of a list and a dictionary. With the joint part being the list string and dictionary key. Please see the example:

```
status = ["old", "new"]
```

```
scores = {
    "boat A" : {
            "min": 5,
            "max": 6
    },
    "boat B" : {
            "min": 5,
            "max": 6
    }
}
```

The result crossing join:

```
cross_join = {
    "boat A old" : {
            "min": 5,
            "max": 6
    },
    "boat B old" : {
            "min": 5,
            "max": 6
    },
    "boat A new" : {
            "min": 5,
            "max": 6
    },
    "boat B new" : {
            "min": 5,
            "max": 6
    }
}
```

Edit: my approach is to loop through the dictionary and append to the key. It works, but its not a beautiful or fast approach given these lists and dictionary's are huge.

Comment: OK, and what did you try and where exactly did it fail?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension

```
res = {f'{k} {x}': v for x in status for k, v in scores.items()}
print(res)
```

Comment: Or: `for x, (k, v) in product(status, scores.items())`